# BigQuery function to collapse row data into JSON or structure

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for a way to group by a number of columns in BigQuery but keep more detail than otherwise possible of the rows being aggregated.

Data:

```
ID     A        B        C       D  
2      1        2        3       4
2      2        3        4       5 
1      1        2        1       3
```

How my query will look something like this:

```
SELECT id, TAKE_ANY(a), sum(b), count(d), max(d), MAGIC(a,b,c,d) FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

And the output I would like is something like:

```
1, 1, 2, 1, 3, [ (1,2,1,3)]
2, 2, 5, 2, 5, [ (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5) ]
```

Anything exist like the MAGIC function that will package the data into a structure of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below option (for BigQuery Standard SQL) is for the case when by `[ (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5) ]` you actually mean STRING vs. ARRAY of STRUCTs (which is not very clear from question but i see possible)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  ANY_VALUE(a) any_a, 
  SUM(b) sum_b, 
  COUNT(d) count_d, 
  MAX(d) max_d, 
  FORMAT('[%s]', STRING_AGG(FORMAT('(%i,%i,%i,%i)', a, b, c, d), ',')) a_b_c_d
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY id
```

If to apply to dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2 id, 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 4 d UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 1, 2, 1, 3 
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  ANY_VALUE(a) any_a, 
  SUM(b) sum_b, 
  COUNT(d) count_d, 
  MAX(d) max_d, 
  FORMAT('[%s]', STRING_AGG(FORMAT('(%i,%i,%i,%i)', a, b, c, d), ',')) a_b_c_d
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

result will be

```
Row id  any_a   sum_b   count_d max_d   a_b_c_d  
1   1   1       2       1       3       [(1,2,1,3)]  
2   2   1       5       2       5       [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your select list, use ARRAY_AGG with the STRUCT function. For example,

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a, b, c, d))
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

This will return an array containing all the values of those columns for each group.